# Webvirtmgr and novnc: unrecognized service after installing novnc on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I can't seem to figure out why novnc is not working. I have installed it using the guide [here](https://github.com/retspen/webvirtmgr/wiki/Install-WebVirtMgr)

```
apt-get install novnc
service novnc stop
novnc: unrecognized service

#updatedb && locate novnc
/root/webvirtmgr/conf/conf.d/webvirtmgr-novnc
/root/webvirtmgr/conf/initd/webvirtmgr-novnc-arch
/root/webvirtmgr/conf/initd/webvirtmgr-novnc-gentoo
/root/webvirtmgr/conf/initd/webvirtmgr-novnc-redhat
/root/webvirtmgr/conf/initd/webvirtmgr-novnc-suse
/root/webvirtmgr/conf/initd/webvirtmgr-novnc-ubuntu
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/Orbitron700.ttf
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/Orbitron700.woff
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/base.css
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/base64.js
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/black.css
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/blue.css
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/chrome-app
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/des.js
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/display.js
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/input.js
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/jsunzip.js
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/logo.js
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/playback.js
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/rfb.js
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/ui.js
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/util.js
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/web-socket-js
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/websock.js
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/webutil.js
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/chrome-app/tcp-client.js
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/web-socket-js/README.txt
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/web-socket-js/WebSocketMain.swf
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/web-socket-js/swfobject.js
/root/webvirtmgr/static/js/novnc/web-socket-js/web_socket.js
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novnc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_novnc-0.4_dfsg_1_20130425_git4973b9cc80.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/cmd/novnc.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/cmd/novnc.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/cmd/novncproxy.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/cmd/novncproxy.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novnc/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novnc/__init__.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novnc/img2js.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novnc/img2js.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novnc/json2graph.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novnc/json2graph.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novnc/web.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novnc/web.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novnc/websocket.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novnc/websocket.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novnc/websockify.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novnc/websockify.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novnc/wsproxy.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novnc/wsproxy.pyc
/usr/share/novnc
/usr/share/doc/novnc
/usr/share/doc/python-novnc
/usr/share/doc/novnc/LICENSE.txt
/usr/share/doc/novnc/README.md.gz
/usr/share/doc/novnc/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/novnc/copyright
/usr/share/doc/python-novnc/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/python-novnc/copyright
/usr/share/novnc/favicon.ico
/usr/share/novnc/images
/usr/share/novnc/include
/usr/share/novnc/vnc.html
/usr/share/novnc/vnc_auto.html
/usr/share/novnc/images/clipboard.png
/usr/share/novnc/images/connect.png
/usr/share/novnc/images/ctrlaltdel.png
/usr/share/novnc/images/disconnect.png
/usr/share/novnc/images/drag.png
/usr/share/novnc/images/favicon.ico
/usr/share/novnc/images/favicon.png
/usr/share/novnc/images/keyboard.png
/usr/share/novnc/images/mouse_left.png
/usr/share/novnc/images/mouse_middle.png
/usr/share/novnc/images/mouse_none.png
/usr/share/novnc/images/mouse_right.png
/usr/share/novnc/images/screen_320x460.png
/usr/share/novnc/images/screen_57x57.png
/usr/share/novnc/images/screen_700x700.png
/usr/share/novnc/images/settings.png
/usr/share/novnc/include/base.css
/usr/share/novnc/include/base64.js
/usr/share/novnc/include/black.css
/usr/share/novnc/include/blue.css
/usr/share/novnc/include/des.js
/usr/share/novnc/include/display.js
/usr/share/novnc/include/input.js
/usr/share/novnc/include/jsunzip.js
/usr/share/novnc/include/logo.js
/usr/share/novnc/include/playback.js
/usr/share/novnc/include/rfb.js
/usr/share/novnc/include/ui.js
/usr/share/novnc/include/util.js
/usr/share/novnc/include/web-socket-js
/usr/share/novnc/include/websock.js
/usr/share/novnc/include/webutil.js
/usr/share/novnc/include/web-socket-js/README.txt
/usr/share/novnc/include/web-socket-js/swfobject.js
/usr/share/novnc/include/web-socket-js/web_socket.js
/var/cache/apt/archives/nova-novncproxy_1%3a2014.1.3-0ubuntu2_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/novnc_1%3a0.4+dfsg+1+20131010+gitf68af8af3d-2_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-novnc_1%3a0.4+dfsg+1+20131010+gitf68af8af3d-2_all.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/novnc.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/novnc.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/novnc.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-novnc.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-novnc.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-novnc.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-novnc.prerm
/var/log/upstart/nova-novncproxy.log
/var/www/static/js/novnc
/var/www/static/js/novnc/Orbitron700.ttf
/var/www/static/js/novnc/Orbitron700.woff
/var/www/static/js/novnc/base.css
/var/www/static/js/novnc/base64.js
/var/www/static/js/novnc/black.css
/var/www/static/js/novnc/blue.css
/var/www/static/js/novnc/chrome-app
/var/www/static/js/novnc/des.js
/var/www/static/js/novnc/display.js
/var/www/static/js/novnc/input.js
/var/www/static/js/novnc/jsunzip.js
/var/www/static/js/novnc/logo.js
/var/www/static/js/novnc/playback.js
/var/www/static/js/novnc/rfb.js
/var/www/static/js/novnc/ui.js
/var/www/static/js/novnc/util.js
/var/www/static/js/novnc/web-socket-js
/var/www/static/js/novnc/websock.js
/var/www/static/js/novnc/webutil.js
/var/www/static/js/novnc/chrome-app/tcp-client.js
/var/www/static/js/novnc/web-socket-js/README.txt
/var/www/static/js/novnc/web-socket-js/WebSocketMain.swf
/var/www/static/js/novnc/web-socket-js/swfobject.js
/var/www/static/js/novnc/web-socket-js/web_socket.js
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the startup script /etc/init.d/novnc is not provided by the Ubuntu package. You can download the web virtual manager novnc startup script with from the Debian package as follows:

```
cd /etc/init.d/
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/retspen/webvirtmgr/master/conf/initd/webvirtmgr-novnc-ubuntu
mv webvirtmgr-novnc-ubuntu novnc
sudo chmod +x novnc
```

and then you can run `service novnc start|stop|status|restart|force-reload`.

(I see you also have this file at /root/webvirtmgr/conf/initd/webvirtmgr-novnc-ubuntu.)

Well this is my dive into this world for today, I hope it has helped you further.

Comment: Didn't work. I'm now going back through the install process to see if I missed something